# Setting a completion size or predicate for unknown number of splited elements in Camel route

Tags: json, split, apache-camel, aggregation

I have a camel route that consume an http service which return a json with several elements I need to correlate through an Id. I don't know how many elements with the same Id are coming in the response, so, How can I set the completion in the aggregation in order to correlate all of them?

These are my routes:

```
 from("direct:getInfo")
      .id("getInfo")
      .setHeader("accept", constant("application/json"))
      .setHeader("authorization", constant("xyz"))
      .setHeader("Cache-Control", constant("no-cache"))
      .setHeader("content-Type", constant("application/json"))
      .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
      .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
      .removeHeader("CamelHttp*")
      .setBody(simple("${null}"))
      .streamCaching()
      .to("http4:someURL") //responses an array of n json elements
      .split().jsonpath("$").streaming()
      .to("direct:splitInfo");


 from("direct:splitInfo")
      .id("splitInfo")
      .aggregate(jsonpath("CustomerId"), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy())
      .completionSize(???) //How must I set the completion in order to correlate all items
      .to("direct:process");
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complete rewrite of the answer due to example in the comments**

Since you want to split and re-aggregate complete JSON payloads, you only need the [Splitter EIP with an aggregation strategy](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc#split-aggregate-requestreply-sample).

If you provide the splitter with the expression to split the payload as well as an aggregation strategy, you don't need a completion criteria at all. Every JSON payload is processed as a "batch".

```
.from(endpoint)
// body = complete JSON payload
.split([split-expression], new MyAggregationStrategy())
    // each element is sent to this bean 
    .to("bean:elementProcessorBean")
    // you must end the splitter 
.end()  
// here you get the complete re-aggregated JSON payload
// how it is re-aggregated is up to MyAggregationStrategy
```

Check out the linked Splitter documentation for an example.

Comment: Hi burki, thanks for your answer. I sorry for the unclear question, I am try to be more specific. Yes, I have a big JSON payload and I need aggregate elements by customerId, the problem is that I need aggregate ALL elements but I don't know how many are there in the JSON, for this reason I don't set a size for completion. The JSON payload arrives once a time, I mean, can't set a timeout. I have tried with `.completion(simple("${exchangeProperty.CamelSplitComplete} == true"))` but doesn't work, the aggregator doesn't correlate nothing.

Comment: I have tried with `.completionOnNewCorrelationGroup()` too, but this only works if the JSON elements with the same `customerId` arrives grouped by

Comment: You mean you want to re-aggregate ALL elements of the payload?

Comment: Maybe with an example. This is the payload: `[
  {
    "customerId": "A101020",
    "account": 123
  },
  {
    "customerId": "A252543",
    "account": 987
  },
  {
    "customerId": "A101020",
    "account": 234
  },
  {
    "customerId": "A252543",
    "account": 876 
  },
  {
    "customerId": "A101020",
    "account": 345
  },
  {
    "customerId": "A101020",
    "account": 456
  },
  {
    "customerId": "A252543",
    "account": 876 
  }
]`

Comment: and this is the result I need: `{
  "A101020": [
    {
      "account": 123
    },
    {
      "account": 234
    },
    {
      "account": 345
    },
    {
      "account": 456
    }
  ],
  "A252543": [
    {
      "account": 987
    },
    {
      "account": 876 
    },
    {
      "account": 876 
    }
  ]
}` thanks for your attention burki.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer, you don't need a completion criteria